# Performance Tuning Oracle SQL involving huge tables

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have an Oracle SQL query that involves joins with 4 large tables along with few small tables.
Large tables are TBL_1, TBL_2, TBL_3, TBL4 each having approx 8M records.  Rest are small tables having less than 10K records.

The problem: Query takes more than 3 minutes even if there is no data to return.

The table and index stats are up-to-date.  There are no stale stats on these tables.

I've tried using hints but it didn't work.

Please see my observations below:

Query:

```
    SELECT a.*, ROWNUM AS rnm
      FROM (  SELECT c.idntfr,
             pr.program_name AS "Program",
             e.case_number,
             (SELECT DECODE (s.status_name,
                     'EA', 'A',
                     'ED', 'D',
                     'EU', 'U',
                     s.status_name)
                FROM TBL_5 ms, status s
               WHERE     ms.status_type_cid = 7
                 AND mbr_sid = c.mbr_sid
                 AND ms.status_type_cid = s.status_type_cid
                 AND s.status_cid = ms.status_cid
                 AND ms.oprtnl_flag = 'A'
                 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ms.from_date AND ms.TO_DATE),
             DECODE (
                LENGTH (TRIM (e.social_security_nmbr)),
                NULL, 'Not Available',
                (   SUBSTR (e.social_security_nmbr, 1, 3)
                 || '-'
                 || SUBSTR (e.social_security_nmbr, 4, 2)
                 || '-'
                 || SUBSTR (e.social_security_nmbr, 6, 4)))
                AS "SSN",
             e.last_name || ',' || e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name,
             TO_CHAR (e.injury_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
             DECODE (e.gender_lkpcd,
                 'M', 'Male',
                 'F', 'Female',
                 'U', 'Unknown'),
             e.mbr_sid,
             pr.program_cid,
             e.last_name,
             e.social_security_nmbr,
             e.first_name AS
            FROM TBL_1 c,
             program pr,
             TBL_2 e,
             TBL_3 mai,
             TBL_4 uaxou
           WHERE     c.mbr_sid = e.mbr_sid
             AND c.mbr_sid = mai.mbr_sid
             AND c.oprtnl_flag = 'A'
             AND c.idntfr_type_cid = 423
             AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN c.from_date AND c.TO_DATE
             AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN e.from_date AND e.TO_DATE
             AND e.oprtnl_flag = 'A'
             AND e.status_cid = 2
             AND mai.oprtnl_flag = 'A'
             AND mai.status_cid = 2
             AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN mai.from_date AND mai.TO_DATE
             AND e.program_code = pr.program_code
             AND pr.oprtnl_flag = 'A'
             AND uaxou.user_acct_sid = 1
             AND uaxou.oprtnl_flag = 'A'
             AND SYSDATE BETWEEN uaxou.from_date AND uaxou.TO_DATE
             AND uaxou.org_unit_sid = mai.org_unit_sid
        ORDER BY "Program" ASC) a
     WHERE ROWNUM < 102;
```

There is no data for the following condition

```
    AND uaxou.user_acct_sid = 1
```

Expected Result: Response time should be under 4 seconds if NO data is returned.

Explain Plan:

```
Plan hash value: 2272581586

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                             |   101 | 22220 |  1361   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |     1 |    58 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |     1 |    58 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TBL_5                       |     1 |    31 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | XIF1TBL_5                   |     8 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | XPKSTATUS                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | STATUS                      |     1 |    27 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |  COUNT STOPKEY                        |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |   VIEW                                |                             |   169 | 37180 |  1361   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |    NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |   169 | 36166 |   767   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |     NESTED LOOPS                      |                             | 11904 | 36166 |   767   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |      NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |    62 | 11284 |   333   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                             |    45 |  6660 |   108   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |    33 |  3564 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PROGRAM                     |     5 |    70 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |          INDEX FULL SCAN              | XAK1OWCP_PROGRAM            |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TBL_2                       |    20 |  1880 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | TBL_1                       |     1 |    40 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | TUNE_WS_19NOV10_X2          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | TBL_3                       |     1 |    34 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | XIE2_TBL_3                  |     3 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | XIF3TBL_4                   |   192 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | TBL_4                       |     3 |    96 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("MS"."STATUS_TYPE_CID"=7 AND "MS"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "MS"."TO_DATE">=SYSDATE@! AND 
          "MS"."FROM_DATE"<=SYSDATE@!)
   4 - access("MBR_SID"=:B1)
   5 - access("S"."STATUS_TYPE_CID"=7 AND "S"."STATUS_CID"="MS"."STATUS_CID")
   7 - filter(ROWNUM<102)
  14 - filter("PR"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A')
  16 - filter("E"."PROGRAM_CODE"="PR"."PROGRAM_CODE" AND "E"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "E"."STATUS_CID"=2 AND 
          "E"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("FROM_DATE"))<=TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)) AND 
          "E"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TO_DATE"))>=TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
  17 - filter("C"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "C"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
  18 - access("C"."MBR_SID"="E"."MBR_SID" AND "C"."IDNTFR_TYPE_CID"=423 AND "C"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A')
  19 - filter("MAI"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "MAI"."STATUS_CID"=2 AND "MAI"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND 
          "MAI"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
  20 - access("C"."MBR_SID"="MAI"."MBR_SID")
  21 - access("UAXOU"."USER_ACCT_SID"=1)
  22 - filter("UAXOU"."ORG_UNIT_SID"="MAI"."ORG_UNIT_SID" AND "UAXOU"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND 
          "UAXOU"."FROM_DATE"<=SYSDATE@! AND "UAXOU"."TO_DATE">=SYSDATE@!)
```

This is output of query from v$parameter

```
    NAME                                |   VALUE
    compatible                          |   12.2.0
    optimizer_adaptive_plans            |   TRUE
    optimizer_adaptive_reporting_only   |   FALSE
    optimizer_features_enable           |   12.2.0.1
```

This is the explain plan after adding GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS showing the actual cardinality values:

```
    Plan hash value: 2272581586

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                             | Name                        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                             |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TBL_5                       |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | XIF1TBL_5                   |      0 |      8 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | XPKSTATUS                   |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | STATUS                      |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  7 |  COUNT STOPKEY                        |                             |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   8 |   VIEW                                |                             |      1 |    169 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   9 |    NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |      1 |    169 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  10 |     NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |      1 |  11904 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  11 |      NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |      1 |     62 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  12 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                             |      1 |     45 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  13 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |      1 |     33 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 14 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PROGRAM                     |      1 |      5 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |
    |  15 |          INDEX FULL SCAN              | XAK1OWCP_PROGRAM            |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
    |* 16 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TBL_2                       |      1 |     20 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | TBL_1                   |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 18 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | TUNE_WS_19NOV10_X2          |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 19 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | TBL_3                       |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 20 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | XIE2_TBL_3                  |      0 |      3 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 21 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | XIF3TBL_4           |      0 |    192 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 22 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | TBL_4                   |      0 |      3 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       3 - filter(("MS"."STATUS_TYPE_CID"=7 AND "MS"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "MS"."TO_DATE">=SYSDATE@! AND 
              "MS"."FROM_DATE"<=SYSDATE@!))
       4 - access("MBR_SID"=:B1)
       5 - access("S"."STATUS_TYPE_CID"=7 AND "S"."STATUS_CID"="MS"."STATUS_CID")
       7 - filter(ROWNUM<102)
      14 - filter("PR"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A')
      16 - filter(("E"."PROGRAM_CODE"="PR"."PROGRAM_CODE" AND "E"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "E"."STATUS_CID"=2 AND 
              "E"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "E"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
      17 - filter(("C"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "C"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
      18 - access("C"."MBR_SID"="E"."MBR_SID" AND "C"."IDNTFR_TYPE_CID"=423 AND "C"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A')
      19 - filter(("MAI"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "MAI"."STATUS_CID"=2 AND "MAI"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "MAI"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
      20 - access("C"."MBR_SID"="MAI"."MBR_SID")
      21 - access("UAXOU"."USER_ACCT_SID"=1)
      22 - filter(("UAXOU"."ORG_UNIT_SID"="MAI"."ORG_UNIT_SID" AND "UAXOU"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND 
              "UAXOU"."FROM_DATE"<=SYSDATE@! AND "UAXOU"."TO_DATE">=SYSDATE@!))
```

I've tried various hints USE_HASH(c e) and various other combinations, none worked.

One interesting observation, if I comment the condition:

```
    --AND uaxou.user_acct_sid = 1
```

The results came in 7 seconds.  (Obviously, data is returned in this case).
So, what's causing the query to take so long when no data is returned? (i.e. this condition is not commented `AND uaxou.user_acct_sid = 1`)

I let the slow query to finish, it took 10 min 46 seconds.  No data is returned

Here is the explain plan.  I don't know why A-Time doesn't match with actual execution time.

```
    Plan hash value: 2272581586

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                             | Name                        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                             |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TBL_5                       |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | XIF1TBL_5                   |      0 |      8 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | XPKSTATUS                   |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | STATUS                      |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |*  7 |  COUNT STOPKEY                        |                             |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   8 |   VIEW                                |                             |      1 |    169 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |   9 |    NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |      1 |    169 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  10 |     NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |      1 |  11904 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  11 |      NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |      1 |     62 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  12 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                             |      1 |     45 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |  13 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |      1 |     33 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 14 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PROGRAM                     |      1 |      5 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |
    |  15 |          INDEX FULL SCAN              | XAK1OWCP_PROGRAM            |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
    |* 16 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TBL_2                       |      1 |     20 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | TBL_1                       |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 18 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | TUNE_WS_19NOV10_X2          |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 19 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | TBL_3                       |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 20 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | XIE2_TBL_3                  |      0 |      3 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 21 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | XIF3TBL_4                   |      0 |    192 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    |* 22 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | TBL_4                       |      0 |      3 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       3 - filter(("MS"."STATUS_TYPE_CID"=7 AND "MS"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "MS"."TO_DATE">=SYSDATE@! AND 
              "MS"."FROM_DATE"<=SYSDATE@!))
       4 - access("MBR_SID"=:B1)
       5 - access("S"."STATUS_TYPE_CID"=7 AND "S"."STATUS_CID"="MS"."STATUS_CID")
       7 - filter(ROWNUM<102)
      14 - filter("PR"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A')
      16 - filter(("E"."PROGRAM_CODE"="PR"."PROGRAM_CODE" AND "E"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "E"."STATUS_CID"=2 AND 
              "E"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "E"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
      17 - filter(("C"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "C"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
      18 - access("C"."MBR_SID"="E"."MBR_SID" AND "C"."IDNTFR_TYPE_CID"=423 AND "C"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A')
      19 - filter(("MAI"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND "MAI"."STATUS_CID"=2 AND "MAI"."FROM_DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "MAI"."TO_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
      20 - access("C"."MBR_SID"="MAI"."MBR_SID")
      21 - access("UAXOU"."USER_ACCT_SID"=1)
      22 - filter(("UAXOU"."ORG_UNIT_SID"="MAI"."ORG_UNIT_SID" AND "UAXOU"."OPRTNL_FLAG"='A' AND 
              "UAXOU"."FROM_DATE"<=SYSDATE@! AND "UAXOU"."TO_DATE">=SYSDATE@!))
```

Comment: It strikes me as a poorly structured and poorly presented query to begin with. Is it possible to refactor the query? Converting that correlated subquery into a join would be a start, as would using the modern join syntax to emphasise which conditions are used for joining and which for filtering. It also strikes me that every table is being separately filtered on e.g. `oprtnl_flag`, rather than joined on that column. I wonder (without knowing the intended function of the query and the nature of the data) are the dates also being filtered on a range, rather than joined on specific matching date?

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  I did try to convert correlated subquery to a join -- there was hardly any performance improvement.  As of now, all of the data is with OPRTNL_FLAG='A' and dates are used in the filter only to ensure the record is active within system date.  This is how we have built validations in most of the other application queries.  Hope it helps.

Comment: There may not be a performance improvement from any single measure - but it will provide a foundation both for possible performance improvements and for simplifying the visual structure of the query (by moving all joins, to the join clause area of the query). When you say "all of the data is with flag A", do you mean no other flags exist in the database? And I would strongly recommend you introduce some more structure to the query - moving to ANSI-92 joins would be a good start. How long does a simple query against any one of these tables (with the given filtering) take?

Comment: ...clearly, if a query against a single table takes a second or two (consistent with your budget for this query), then it's a case of adding in more logic until you find where performance is suddenly degrading and isolating the factor responsible. It is best to start from the table which is most capable of restricting the number of rows returned in subsequent tables.

Comment: @Steve, as of now, all data exists with OPRTNL_FLAG ='A' since we just converted the data from the legacy system. Once the system is in operations, it will have other flags too, but most of the records will be with 'A'.  I've already tried isolating the tables and running with filter criteria, the results are within 2 seconds.  It's impacting performance when I join all 4 big tables together.

Comment: I see. I can't see any obvious simple fix here. The solution to problems like these tends to be trial-and-error in nature. Starting with the table in which the relevant rows can be filtered to a minimum, and then joining to the next in a fashion that allows filtering to a minimum and performance remains acceptable, and so on - building the query exactly in the order as you expect it to be executed, and solving any inefficiencies that arise at each step (such as adjusting indexes, adjusting database structure, materialising views, building the joins or filtering in an alternative order, etc.).

Comment: At this point really need to see the table and index definitions before we could proceed much further.

Comment: Thanks for all help Steve and RBarryYoung. The stats were gathered a week ago and there were no stale stats in DBA_TAB_STATISTICS, but as it was not helping, I reached out to DBA and he gathered stats again on the underlying table and indexes.  Now the query is returning results in less than a second.  Question: How do I figure out if table and index stats need to be gathered again even if DBA_TAB_STATISCIS.STALE_STATS='NO' ?

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive plans may improve the execution plan.

You tagged the question as 12c but it looks like the execution plan is not using adaptive plans for some reason.  Adaptive plans let Oracle change operations at run time, such as switching between NESTED LOOPS and HASH JOINS.

NESTED LOOPS are good for a small percentage of rows, and HASH JOINS are good for a large percentage of rows.  Since the ROWS estimates are all small, but the query runs for three minutes, I would guess the optimizer is significantly underestimating the cardinality of the expressions and joins, and is using too many NESTED LOOPs.

If adaptive plans were enabled the execution plan should have this at the bottom:

```
Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

Since that Note is missing, I would guess there is a parameter issue on your database preventing adaptive plans.  Run the below query and see if one of the features is turned off, or if the features are set to a version lower than 12:

```
select name, value
from v$parameter
where name in (
    'optimizer_adaptive_features', --12.1 only
    'optimizer_adaptive_plans', --12.2+
    'optimizer_adaptive_reporting_only',
    'optimizer_features_enable',
    'compatible'
    )
order by 1;
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I'm not sure why adaptive plans aren't working for you.  If nobody can figure that out, then we'll need to investigate the execution plan actual values to find out precisely which operations are slow.

There are at least two ways to get the actual numbers.  If you can change and re-run the offending query, you can use the hint [GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-know-if-the-cardinality-estimates-in-a-plan-are-accurate).

```
--Run slow query and wait for it to finish:
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from dual;

--Find the SQL_ID of the query using some distinctive text:
select *
from v$sql
where lower(sql_fulltext) like '%gather_plan_statistics%';

--Generate execution plan with actual values.
select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID from above', format=>'allstats last'));
```

If you cannot alter the query, you can use SQL Monitor reports to find the actual values.  (This feature requires Enterprise Edition and a tuning pack license.)

```
--Generate SQL Monitoring Report:
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID from above') from dual;
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Are you 100% sure you've found the right SQL_ID?  You might want to double check `GV$SQL`.  Sometimes the case is switched, if the SQL is submitted from an application or PL/SQL block.  And rarely the real SQL statement will age out of `GV$SQL`, if someone runs `alter system flush shared_pool;`, or stats are gathered, or if you wait too long.

If that is truly the right execution plan, no time is spent on the query.  Normally this means that time must be spent by the network sending the results, or the application processing the results.  But since there are no rows returned a network or application issue doesn't sound likely.

If the time is spent on the database, but not on that query, then I would guess it's either a parsing issue or a recursive query issue.  Parsing issues can be found by tracing, but those are caused by extremely unusual problems or queries, and likely isn't the case here.

Perhaps one of the queries Oracle uses to gather metadata is taking too long.  For many queries, Oracle needs to run other queries that check privileges, dynamic sampling, etc.  You may need to tune one of those *other* queries, and the below statements can help with that painful process:

```
--Clear existing run times (be careful running this on production).
--(This won't flush queries that are actively running.)
alter system flush shared_pool;

--Run your slow SQL statement here.
--...

--Now look for anything "weird" that has taken up most of the time. 
select elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, gv$sql.*
from gv$sql
order by seconds desc;
```

Comment: @AJ. Your parameters look fine, I'm surprised adaptive plans aren't being used here.  I must be missing something here, but I'm not sure what.  Also, the execution plan with actual statistics does not match the problem you described.  The actual run time is less than a second.  Can you generate the actual numbers for the slow query instead of the fast query?

Comment: could you please help, how do I generate the actual numbers for the fast query?

Comment: @AJ. I added some details about generating actual numbers.  Although I believe you'll want them for the *slow* query, not the fast query.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added comments.  I'm still puzzled though

Comment: Thanks for all help Jon. The stats were gathered a week ago and there were no stale stats in DBA_TAB_STATISTICS, but as it was not helping, I reached out to DBA and he gathered stats again on the underlying table and indexes.  Now the query is returning results in less than a second.  Question: How do I figure out if table and index stats need to be gathered again even if DBA_TAB_STATISCIS.STALE_STATS='NO' ?